# Prevent Airflow from triggering on scheduler restart

Tags: airflow

My Airflow Scheduler went down for some reason, and when I re-started it, all the DAGS triggered simultaneously. It was as if it was catching up from the missed jobs. Also, it seems when I modify a DAG, the workflow triggers. These unexpected triggers corrupt my data and loses trust in the system.

Is there a way to prevent a DAG running unexpectedly unless it is the exact time (no catch-up) or unless it is manually triggered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The airflow scheduler will, at a minimum, attempt to run the current schedule interval when it is online to do so. This means that if the scheduler process is offline for a period of time, when it comes back online it will reconcile which jobs should have run and attempt to start those jobs.

There is some control using `catchup`, which tells the scheduler that only the *latest* job should be run and schedule intervals other than the latest that were missed do not need to be run.

Some info on `catchup` here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#catchup

> Is there a way to prevent a DAG running unexpectedly unless it is the exact time (no catch-up) or unless it is manually triggered?

There is no way to tell Airflow to only attempt to schedule the job at the *exact* time the job is supposed to run (and never attempt again after the fact). You can set the schedule interval to `None` and the job will never be scheduled, however. You can manually trigger the job through the UI or via the Airflow API in this case.

https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/dag-run.html#cron-presets

```
preset | meaning
-------+----------------------------------------------------------------
None   | Don’t schedule, use for exclusively “externally triggered” DAGs
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It sounds like the best thing I can do is ensure the scheduler never goes down, or if it goes down, it reboots quickly so it doesn't miss a job.